# Jquery - if not keypress for 1 second then do something

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a function that

-on keypress show a div

-if the user stop typing, after a second do something

```
$('input:text').bind('focus blur', function() {
    $('input:text').keypress(function() {
        $("#imagefield").show();
    });
});
```

I don't know how to catch if the user stop typing for a second.
Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: _"on keypress show a div"_ At first `keypress` , show div immediately ?, or wait 1 second _then_ do something ?

Comment: show a div immediately.

Comment: If `blur`, `focus` event occur, without `keypress` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start a timer when the user presses a key. Each time he presses another key, stop the old timer and start another one.

```js
var keytimer;
$("input:text").keypress(function() {
  clearTimeout(keytimer);
  $("#output").empty();
  keytimer = setTimeout(doSomething, 1000);
});

function doSomething() {
  $("#output").text("Time!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="output"></div>
```